# C# Telerik RadGrid EditFormType="AutoGenerated"

Tags: c#

How can I reach each control in the popup window of the Telerik RadGrid if it is generated automatically - EditFormType="AutoGenerated"?

For example, if i have a column price, when i press edit, a label price and a textbox appears. How can I access this textbox (the textbox of price) to update it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`InsertCommand`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.radgrid-insertcommand_ev.html) handler (and there is an [`EditCommand`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.radgrid-editcommand_ev.html) handler) on the RadGrid, and then use the Item property in the [`GridCommandEventArgs`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.gridcommandeventargs.html) to pull the out [`GridEditableItem`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.grideditableitem.html) which gives you access to the controls.

I don't have any code to hand, but there is a [post on the Telerik forums that nicely illustrates how to get access to the controls](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/getting-values-from-controls-using-editformtype-autogenerated.aspx#1635490).